# Constructing std::string like an array

Tags: c++, string

I want to construct a std::string object like an array:

```
std::string str("");
str[0] = 'A';
str[1] = 'b';
str[2] = 'h';
str[3] = 'i';
str[4] = '\0';
std::cout<<str;
```

But it doesnt print the string. What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
std::string (4, ' ');
```

instead of

```
std::string("");
```

basic_string's operator[] returns a reference to the specified character, but since your string is empty, it contains no characters.

Comment: Actually I don't like that constructor of std::string because if you can't remember the order and put the character first it will still compile and give you the wrong thing. If you do std::string(' ', 4) it will give you a string of length 32 (ASCII value of space) filled with ASCII 4 characters. Unfortunate problem of char having implicit conversions with size_t.

Comment: @CashCow: I agree, it's unseemly that `char` would both represent a character and behave as an integer...

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, `std::string` is not a C-string.  You do not need to NULL-terminate it.  Secondly, the `[]` operator is only valid for indices which are `< std::string::length()`, meaning that at least N elements must be allocated in advance before you can access an element between `0` and `N-1`.

```
std::string str(4); // construct a string of size 4
str[0] = 'A';
str[1] = 'b';
str[2] = 'h';
str[3] = 'i';
std::cout << str;
```

Edit: But also see [Johnsyweb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448177/constructing-stdstring-like-an-array/4448320#4448320).  The big advantage of `std::string` over C-strings is that you don't have to worry about memory allocation.  You can use the `+=` operator or `push_back` member function, and can build the string character-by-character without worrying about how much memory to reserve.

Comment: shouldn't it be std::string(4, ' '); ?

Comment: @Abhi: the second argument is optional, if not present it will default to `'\0'` (instead of the space). It is up to you to determine whether you prefer uninitialized elements to be spaces or NUL characters.

Answer (score 2):

> What am i missing?

You are missing the whole point of using a `std::string`. That approach may work for arrays of `char`, but not for strings.

Consider [`std::string::operator +=`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/) instead.

Comment: In all likelihood, this is actually the best answer.

Comment: To be honest, I cannot even understand why anyone would want to take that approach with a `char` array.

Answer (score 1):

You allocated the string to be "", that is, exactly 0 bytes long.

You are then trying to write chars outside of bounds of the string - which doesn't work.

Comment: I see. Isnt there a way to modify the string declared above then except using insert()?

Comment: @Abhi: Look at the documentation for string ( [SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html),  [C++Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) ). There are ( [too](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) ) many different member functions that operate on the string, including `resize()` that will, well, resize the string so you can make it grow.

Answer (score -1):

you should create a space in the memory for your array

```
using namespace std;

char str[5];

str[0] = 'A';    
str[1] = 'b';    
str[2] = 'h';    
str[3] = 'i';    
str[4] = '\0';

cout << str ;
```

Comment: i want to use std::string. I know i can do that with a char array.